# How do I create a condition that will not display a field if the field is empty?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using advanced custom fields (ACF). I would like to not display the ACF  repeater field `the_sub_field('feature_image_post');` if the field is empty. I wrapped the field in a div and wrote a display = none using CSS if the field is empty but I'm sure there is a better way of doing this. My logic doesn't seem to work.

```
 <?php

        // check if the repeater field has rows of data

        if( have_rows('repeat_field') ):

          // loop through the rows of data
            while ( have_rows('repeat_field') ) : the_row();

                // display a sub field value

                echo '<span class="place-name">';
                  the_sub_field('place_name');
                echo '</span>';


      if (!empty (get_sub_field('feature_image_post')))  {

       echo '<div class="post-feature" style="display:block;">'; 
       echo the_sub_field('feature_image_post'); 
       echo '</div>';

      } 

      else {
       echo '<div class="post-feature" style="display:none;">' 
       echo the_sub_field('feature_image_post'); 
       echo '</div>';

      }
            endwhile;

        else :

            // no rows found

        endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for an else statement here. If the field hasn't been set then you simply don't show anything.

My approach would be to use `get_sub_field()` and assign the result to a variable as part of the conditional.

The default return value for an image in ACF is an array of values so I'm going to assume that's what you have.

Example:

```
if ( $feature_image_post = get_sub_field( 'feature_image_post' ) )  {
    echo '<div class="post-feature">'; 
    printf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" />', esc_url( $feature_image_post['url'] ), esc_attr( $feature_image_post['title'] ) );
    echo '</div>';
}
```

One final point to raise is the difference between `get_sub_field()` and `the_sub_field()`. In your original code you were trying to echo `the_sub_field()`. `get_...` will return a value whereas `the_...` will output it making `echo` redundant in that context.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (! empty(get_sub_field('feature_image_post'))) {
    echo '<div class="post-feature" style="display:block;">';
    the_sub_field('feature_image_post'); 
    echo '</div>';
}
```

and that's it. in this case where `get_sub_field('feature_image_post')` is empty it will just skip the whole part.

as far as I know - `the_` in ACF means that it display the data, so you won't need `echo` before that.

and please always check if you have closed your `echo` with `;`, because in the example you didn't.

Comment: Understood so will I need an elseif statement to create another condition? Should my code work?

Comment: The code above will work for checking if there is that value, if is not, then just skip and show nothing. You can, of course, use `else {}` to display something else in case when there is no featured image. `elseif {}` if you have another condition to make. 

if the condition is not connected to not having that first one, then just another separate `if {}`.